# Amazon AWS IAM Policy based in time of day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

The IAM service is Amazon AWS permits the creation of policies based on date, as described here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition

This seems to refer to allowing/denying actions based on calendar date.

eg after 12:00 on March 1st 2015

Is it possible to create a condition that permits/denies action on the basis of time of day

eg between 14:00 and 18:00 on any given day?